# Why does Illustrator changes the color of an object when I copy it and paste it in another Illustrator document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk

As the title say, I've got this issue with Illustrator. I'm working on a CMYK document and if I copy and paste an object to another CMYK document, the colors of the object changes in an "unsaturated" version of the same color.

Comment: Are both documents made from the start as CMYK or the source one was RGB switched to CMYK?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY both are in CMYK from the start

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? Does it happen with any document or is it a specific one? Is the color actual CMYK or Pantone or spot or...?
 That might help figuring it out.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. Copying and pasting objects with CMYK colours applied from one CMYK document into another changes nothing.

Comment: Are the colour proofing settings the same in each document?

Comment: It happens with Pantone colors, I've noticed that in the swatches panel if i check the color on both document, one says Spot color and the other one (same color obviously) says Book color

Comment: Nope, can't be that either. I still can't replicate the problem.  If I copy a bunch of objects with Pantone Solid (spot) colours into another CMYK document, nothing changes. The spot colours are still spot colours, and they look exactly the same.

Comment: "Book colour" is just the colour mode of the swatch options - its used to default back to the colour from the Pantone swatch book, for example if you have adjusted the colour using one of the other mode with colour sliders.  Remember, you can't really adjust a spot colour, sure you can change the sliders, but when it's printed the printer is going to use the spot colour specified.  Spot colours are solid ink - made from a fixed formula.  Did you adjust the spot colours??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a lot in comments, now I think have enough info to attempt an answer.

Spot colours are not CMYK colours.  They are a single solid coloured ink - mixed from other colours according to a formula guide created by Pantone.

If you adjust the spot colours in Illustrator using the colour swatch options by moving the sliders, you are only changing the display colour, the colour isn't really changing.  When you copy and paste the colours you changed into a new document, they are reverting to the colour swatch book (the Book colour) - because you can't edit spot colours like that.

Perhaps it's time to familiarise yourself with CMYK colours versus Spot Colours, what they are and how they differ.

Comment: I made some tries and you are right, the Pantone color has been changed moving the sliders. All this confusion happened becuase I was working in a document made by someone else so I couldn't understand this weird behavior. Thank you